# Is it a good practice to copy Go's binary distribution into `/usr/local/`?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

From Go's install webpage,

> Download the archive and extract it into /usr/local, creating a Go
>   tree in /usr/local/go. For example:
>
> ```
> tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz
> ```
>
> Choose the archive file appropriate for your installation. For
>   instance, if you are installing Go version 1.2.1 for 64-bit x86 on
>   Linux, the archive you want is called go1.2.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz.
>
> (Typically these commands must be run as root or through sudo.)
>
> Add /usr/local/go/bin to the PATH environment variable. You can do
>   this by adding this line to your /etc/profile (for a system-wide
>   installation) or $HOME/.profile:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
> ```

The directory hierarchy of my `/usr/local` is

```
$ ls /usr/local/
bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src  texlive
```

Does the extracted Go's binary distribution fit into `/usr/local`?
Is it a good practice to copy Go's binary distribution into `/usr/local/`?

If not, what is your recommendation about where to put it?
Is `/opt` or my home directory a better place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY), `/usr/local/` is meant for exactly that:

> The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally.

The [alternative would be](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) `/opt`:

> `/opt` is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages.
> A package to be installed in `/opt` must locate its static files in a separate `/opt/<package>` or `/opt/<provider>` directory tree,

Even in `/usr/local`, a separate tree is useful for keeping different packages separate from each other, and simplifying updates, removals and keeping multiple versions of the same program present. The choice between `/usr/local` is pretty much up to you as the system administrator.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is to **NOT** follow the install instructions on the Go language web site.

Instead, install the packages for your distribution.

Debian, for example has golang 1.6.1 packaged, along with hundreds of Go libraries.

Ubuntu has 1.6.1 too.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/golang

`apt-get install golang` will install the compiler, docs and golang source.

`apt-cache show -n golang` will give you a list of all other packages with "golang" in the package name - at first glance, nowhere near as many as Debian.

---

If you really must compile and install it yourself, you should at least use `checkinstall`:

> CheckInstall keeps track of all the files created or modified by your installation script ("make install", "make install_modules", "setup", etc), builds a standard binary package and installs it in your system giving you the ability to uninstall it with your distribution's standard package management utilities.
>
> Homepage: http://checkinstall.izto.org

Use it for any Go libraries you compile too.

Comment: This is bad advice. If you actually want to use `go` itself, install following instructions on the website. If you want to use a program that uses the `go` command and is in the package repository, use `apt` - that is why Go is included as a package in the first place. There is no reason to use the `apt-get` packages if you are a Go programmer.

Comment: @MichaelYounkin There are excellent reasons to use packages if you're a programmer who cares about not leaving random crap strewn all over their system.   Packages are installable, uninstallable, and upgradeable - without fuss or mess.  Following some bone-head's brawndo-installer ("wget $URL | sudo bash") creates a mess that will one day break something important.

Comment: Installing some tarball built in some unknown environment will likely lead to some kind of DLL hell too.  There can be subtle differences between different versions of libs (even where the soname hasn't changed) that can break programs built against a different version of a lib -- or, worse, silently change the behaviour to produce different results.   Distro packages are built and tested against a standard set of libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Following the installation instructions is usually good practice.

I think it sounds like quite a good idea to keep the Go stuff under `/usr/local/go`. That way you can easily remove the complete installation before updating it by just removing that directory hierarchy.

Nothing stops you from putting it in `/opt` as `/opt/go` or in `/sw` or `$HOME/local` or wherever you want, as long as you add the appropriate path to you `PATH` shell variable.

It is not unheard of for software to create their own hierarchies beneath `/usr/local`.  On some BSD systems, installing the GNU `coreutils` will create `/usr/local/gnu` with things like `gls`, `gcp`, `grm` etc. (the ordinary utilities with a `g` prefix) as symlinks from `/usr/local/bin` into `/usr/local/gnu/bin`.